# \tikzcdset{arrow style=math font} breaks the rendering of arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, tikz-arrows, unicode-math, tikz-cd

The command `\tikzcdset{arrow style=math font}` seems to break the rendering of arrows with the package `tikz-cd`, whatever math font is chosen:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=math font}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        a\arrow[r]&b
    \end{tikzcd}

    \setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        a\arrow[r]&b
    \end{tikzcd}

    \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        a\arrow[r]&b
    \end{tikzcd}

    \setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        a\arrow[r]&b
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

What can be done about this?

**If this is not fixable**, I would also be interested in other ways to make the arrow of `tikz-cd` match the math font.

Comment: It should be `\tikzcdset{arrow style=math font}`, but the stem gets misplaced.

Comment: The effect is quite evident at high resolutions: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HAfu.png)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`tikz-cd` assumes two things when drawing the arrows:

1. That the line width of the arrow is the same as the width of a fraction rule, and
2. that the arrow goes along the math axis.

Both is not true for every math font. Imho it is not possible from inside luatex to get the correct values. You would have to look at the glyph definition with e.g. font forge. The following is not perfect but shows how one can adjust the values:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=math font}

\begin{document}

    \setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

    $\frac{1}{b}\rightarrow xxx$

    \begin{tikzcd}
        a\arrow[r]&b
    \end{tikzcd}

\tikzcdset{every arrow/.append style={line width=0.52pt}}%smaller    
\pgfmathdeclarefunction*{axis_height}{0}{%
    \begingroup%      
      \pgfmathreturn2.65pt % smaller than the original
    \endgroup}% 
    \begin{tikzcd}
        a\arrow[r]&b
    \end{tikzcd}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I also tried down arrows, they also look very good now. Could you maybe add, which the values from the glyph definition are needed, and how they must be used?

Comment: You need the line width and the position of the line relative to the baseline. Btw: The values naturally depend on the font size. So the code above is not meant as usable directly, only as proof of concept.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I really appreciated your answer. +1

Comment: I just realized that this might be one of the situations where using `em` is better than `pt`, making the solution independent of global font size.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the answer by Ulrike Fischer I wrote a small package which stores the values for a few commonly used fonts, namely: `Libertinus Math`, `TeX Gyre Pagella Math`, `TeX Gyre Schola Math`, `TeX Gyre Bonum Math`, `STIX Two Math`, `Cambria Math`. I thought I would share them here in case someone encounters the same problem. Maybe I will also updated the answer in case I add more fonts.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mycd}

\RequirePackage{tikz-cd}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{tikz-cd}}

\newcommand{\tikzcdarrowdimens}[2]{%
    \tikzcdset{every arrow/.append style={line width=#1}}%
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction*{axis_height}{0}{%
        \begingroup%      
        \pgfmathreturn#2%
        \endgroup%
    }%
}

\DeclareOption{Libertinus}{%
    \tikzcdset{arrow style=math font}%
    \tikzcdarrowdimens{0.052em}{0.250em}%
}

\DeclareOption{Pagella}{%
    \tikzcdset{arrow style=math font}%
    \tikzcdarrowdimens{0.060em}{0.250em}%
}

\DeclareOption{Schola}{%
    \tikzcdset{arrow style=math font}%
    \tikzcdarrowdimens{0.070em}{0.260em}%
}

\DeclareOption{Bonum}{%
    \tikzcdset{arrow style=math font}%
    \tikzcdarrowdimens{0.072em}{0.260em}%
}

\DeclareOption{STIX}{%
    \tikzcdset{arrow style=math font}%
    \tikzcdarrowdimens{0.068em}{0.259em}%
}

\DeclareOption{Cambria}{%
    \tikzcdset{arrow style=math font}%
    \tikzcdarrowdimens{0.06494140625em}{0.285888671875em}%
}

\ProcessOptions\relax
```

Basic usage is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\usepackage[Libertinus]{mycd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        a\arrow[r]&b
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How would go about adding an entry in your package for Minion Math?

Comment: @msx Unfortunately, I don't own this font.

Comment: What would be involved if I were to do it myself?

Comment: Could you add kpfonts please?